# how to read many images in python and enumerate at the same time

Tags: python, arrays, image, loops, image-processing

I am trying to read many images at the same time and enumerating them.
Here the values of the first image will be image[0] and the second is image[1]

```
import mahotas as mh

filelist = ["khkg.png", "sss.png", "skh.png", "syiy.png"]

image = []
for imagefile in filelist:
    for i in range(len(filelist)):
        image[i]=mh.imread(imagefile, as_grey=True)
```

And i am getting this error:

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: Use `image.append(mh.imread(imagefile, as_grey=True))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set up the list beforehand, you'd have to use:

```
image = [[] for x in range(len(filelist))]
```

when you call the storage list.

Comment: Otherwise, you're trying to put items in an empty list.  You need to tell Python how large the list is beforehand if you want to populate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just append to the list as you move over the files.

```
import mahotas as mh

filelist = ["khkg.png", "sss.png", "skh.png", "syiy.png"]

image = []
for imagefile in filelist:
  for i in range(len(filelist)):
    image.append(mh.imread(imagefile, as_grey=True))
```

Comment: The inner `for` loop is almost certainly unnecessary. I don't think the questioner wants four copies of each of his images added to his list.